# PrettyPhoto image save as

Tags: jquery, gallery, lightbox, prettyphoto

I have a problem with the class pretty photo, I have no possible meaning to save the image that I'm seeing, there is a solution to this problem?

This is class jquery

http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/

is possible to give save image as... if i try the right click... I don't have the option to save the image

a try change css, but the problem is not them

prettyphoto is a clone of lightbox
my version is 3.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use this:

```
$('img').bind('contextmenu', function(e) {
    return false;
});
```

or this other solution that you can find in [this guy blog:](http://www.bloggersentral.com/2012/05/disable-right-click-on-images.html)

```
function nocontext(e) {
        var clickedTag = (e==null) ? event.srcElement.tagName : e.target.tagName;
        if (clickedTag == "IMG") {
            alert(alertMsg);
            return false;
        }
    }
    var alertMsg = "Image context menu is disabled";
    document.oncontextmenu = nocontext;
```

or you could use something like this to [plugin](http://www.javascripttoolbox.com/lib/contextmenu/) to manage or make right click menus, according to their docs and sample you only need this to create a custom menu

```
var menu1 = [
  {'Option 1':function(menuItem,menu) { alert("You clicked Option 1!"); } },
  $.contextMenu.separator,
  {'Option 2':function(menuItem,menu) { alert("You clicked Option 2!"); } }
];
$(function() {
  $('.cmenu1').contextMenu(menu1,{theme:'vista'});
});
```

But check it out and do whatever works better for you.

Comment: what you mean cleaner? i added another way to do it, disable right click it is the cleaner way to do it. people can still get the images if they look in the source, i mean it is so easy instegram site has disable right click, but still getting images it just about looking in the source. so i think this is the best way to do it..